# Excel keep getting locked from ms access vba code

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am trying to export excel from ms access vba code. I am able to do most of the part except couple of problems.

1) The excel application keep getting locked and when i try to open spreadsheet it says spreadsheet locked for editing by myself. I have released all the variables at the end as well but still no luck.

2) I am not able to open the new "Saved As" spreadsheet automatically and also need to close the original spreadsheet.

I searched extensively on google and went through other questions on stackoverflow but could not figure it out.

Requirement - I want to export excel from ms access. I need take the existing spreadsheet, replace its contents when my code runs and then save as to another worksheet keeping original spreadsheet unchanged. I need to also open the new spreadsheet and present to the user. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub GenerateReport(strFileName As String)
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim xlWB As Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim fpath As String
Dim path As String
Dim fname As String
    With xlObj
     On Error goto errorHandler
    .DisplayAlerts=False
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "tableName", strFileName, True
    Set xlWB = Workbooks.Open(strFileName) 'strFileName consist of full path of spreadsheet
    xlWB.Activate
    fdate = "20200521"
    path = xlWB.path

    ' Some code for formatting excel spreadsheet

    fname = "Temp" & fdate
    xlWB.SaveAs Filename:=path & "\" & fname, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlObj = Nothing

    procdone:
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlObj = Nothing
    Exit Sub

    errorHandler:
    Resume procdone

   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How about `xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=False` ?

Comment: Thanks @PeterT. Now i am able to avoid the first problem where excel was getting locked. Could you please also suggest on how do i automatically open the new "Save As" spreadsheet and present to the user?

Comment: Why don't you Google topic? https://www.educba.com/vba-workbook-open/

Comment: Might also need `xlObj.UserControl = True`.

Comment: Hi @June7 - I did go through it and it says to use WorkBooks.Open method. If i add this statement at the end of my code (Just before where i am setting all the variables to Nothing) then no spreadsheet gets open and instead the excel application gets locked for editing altogether.

Comment: Modify code to run in Access VBA. Still manipulating Excel objects. For your procedure `xlObj.Workbooks.Open …`.

Comment: Or use Shell() to open a file. `Shell("Excel " & path & "\" & fname)` https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/vba-shell

Comment: Or don't close workbook and just set UserControl to True.